# rsync with the --delete option didn't delete the extra folders in destination

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I want to backup data to the destination server, and I try the commmand like this:

```
rsync -Aaq --exclude=folder1/ --exclude=folder2/ --delete /SourceFolder/ /DesinationFolder/
```

I hope to backup data to the destination without some spcific folder, but in the destination still have some other folders, rsync with the --delete option seems didn't delete extra folders in destination.

The desination folder must be exactly the same as the source folder, so the extra folder in destination should be deleted.

What's wrong with me?

Comment: I'm not sure from your description, but... are you looking for the `--delete-excluded` option?

Comment: `--delete-excluded` option can complete my goal, thanks!